# jQuery function is not called when script src is added to head

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, api

I'm a bit of a newbie with sources etc and I took it for granted that I could simply add the script src to the header and then add as many scripts or functions as I wanted after that.  For the most part this is working fine but now I hav an issue that I cannot solve.

I can either have one script running or the other, both will not work in harmony no matter how many different permutations I've tried.  I'm sure there's an easy fix or something I'm missing entirely.  I had a look online for an idiot's guide but didn't find anything of use.

The two function scripts are in different places.  One is in the head and called from the body of the HTML pages, the other is in an include which is added to every page for dynamic links.

This loads everything Except what is within the body

```
<!--Creation and hiding of div to allow images load-->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="../js/helperFunctions.js"></script>

<!-- jQuery (required) -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../js/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

<!-- Syntax highlighting -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../mainCSS/prettify.css" media="screen">
<script src="../js/prettify.js"></script>

<!-- AnythingSlider -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../mainCSS/anythingslider.css">
<script src="../js/jquery.anythingslider.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function(){
            prettyPrint script here;
</script>

<script>
    $(function(){
            slider script here
</script>
```

Whilst this loads the body script but none of the others.:

```
<!-- jQuery (required) -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../js/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

<!-- Syntax highlighting -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../mainCSS/prettify.css" media="screen">
<script src="../js/prettify.js"></script>

<!-- AnythingSlider -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../mainCSS/anythingslider.css">
<script src="../js/jquery.anythingslider.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function(){
            prettyPrint script here;
</script>

<script>
    $(function(){
            slider script here
</script>

   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
   <script src="../js/helperFunctions.js"></script>
```

I then tried putting the script src in the include, including the src twice and lots of other stupid senseless ideas.

If anyone could help it'd be great! Many thanks

Comment: Start by removing the extra jQuery script references (should only be included once) and see what happens. Also, I assume you were just snipping irrelevant code, but your `$(function() {` blocks are being closed in the actual code, correct?

Comment: @JasonP - Hi, yeah I removed all the function code to save space in the question.  They're all closed off.  I just came across another page with far fewer scripts, (one) in the head that also displays the same charateristics

Comment: @JasonP - also, I think that the script src shoudl be the first thing in the head.  Is that right?

Comment: Where they go isn't necessarily important as long as they are included before you try to use `$`. The `<head>` is the standard place for that. Generally, the order of scripts should be the jQuery library, jQuery plugins, your external scripts, then inline script. That may vary on a case by case basis though.

Comment: @JasonP - thankyou, I'll sort them out :)  Should there be a backup src for jquery?  If one link is down?

Comment: You could... but is your site really going to have higher availability than a Google CDN?

Answer (score 1):

Your include jQuery like three times in this code. i'm not sure if thats the problem but it ain't the solution

```
// jquery from jquery.com
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

<!-- jQuery (required) --> // jQuery from google
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../js/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
// both of these are expendable
```

this might cause a conflict since the last one to be included is an older version of the library. you only need only inclusion. I'm assuming your using migrate because you have older jQuery code running in your scripts.

**CODE ERROR**

```
<script>
$(function(){ // syntax error
        prettyPrint script here;
</script>

<script>
$(function(){ // same error
        slider script here
</script>
```

you have syntax errors here, and any script that comes after this code will not run or work.

Comment: Which one shoudl be included?

Comment: which ever one you want. but only one.

Answer (score 0):

I had a function in one f the scripts that was returning an error.  That seemed to be halting the est of the code. -.-

Also only have one instance of jquery in the head now.